# Mousemove animate on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, mousemove

I want to make an animation hover on a div.
But it doesn't work, when my mouse is outsite the div, the animation doesn't work. Why ?

**https://jsfiddle.net/udn5b9fd/**

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
$("span").css({left:e.pageX - 50, top:e.pageY - 50});
});


$("div").hover(

  function() {
  $("span").stop().animate({"height": "100px", "width": "100px"}, 200);
  },
  function() {
  $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0.5"}, 0);
  },
  function() {
  $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, 0);

});
```

Comment: You can't have three functions inside the hover declaration just one for in and one for out .... Which is the expected behavior ? when the span grows then the hover on the div is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several fixes, you should apply:

1. Remove 3rd function from `hover` callback, since it has only 2 parameters: [Jquery Hover](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)
2. Update all the properties in each of the handlers: `opacity, height, width`
3. Add `pointer-events: none` style to your `span` element, to prevent calling `hoverOut` when your mouse under the `span`.

Look at the example for more details: [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/telman/9rrbzwem/)